# Sending Push notifications on iOS using Houston

Tags: ios, bash, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use this framework to send a push notification from my MacBook to my iOS device.

https://github.com/nomad/houston

I've verified that my .pem certificate is working by using this web app:

http://www.pushwatch.com/apns/

[image]

So through the web app the push reaches my phone. Proving that my certificate is ok.

When I try the Houston framework I receive nothing. It however does tell me the push notification is sent out succesfully:

```
Rutgers-MacBook-Pro:Desktop rutger$ apn push "c2d080f7be677353ae654d07ab1ecc54fb894e2757eb2595661216a46d9d6c4f" -c /Users/rutger/Desktop/Runk-Push-Prod/RunkProdPush.pem -m "Hello from the command line! "
1 push notification sent successfully
```

I've also tried it like this:

```
Rutgers-MacBook-Pro:Desktop rutger$ apn push "c2d080f7 be677353 ae654d07 ab1ecc54 fb894e27 57eb2595 661216a4 6d9d6c4f" -c /Users/rutger/Desktop/Runk-Push-Prod/RunkProdPush.pem -m "Hello from the command line! "
1 push notification sent successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I was missing:

```
-e production
```

So my command should've been:

```
apn push "c2d080f7be677353ae654d07ab1ecc54fb894e2757eb2595661216a46d9d6c4f" -e production -c /var/www/html/backend/certs/runkprodpush.pem -m "Hello from the command line! "
```